# include local path in project c++ but building failed?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I have a c++ project in eclipse, ubuntu. The structure project same as:

```
HelloWorld
   - Includes (i had include path: HelloWorld/sources/diagcom)
   - sources
      - diagcom 
        + diagcom.hpp
        + diagcom.cpp
   - main.cpp
```

I had include path HelloWorld/sources/diagcom to Includes and in main.cpp i had include as:

```
#include <diagcom.hpp>
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

but i get an error when build the project

```
"fatal error: diagcom.hpp: No such file or directory"
```

So what wrong in main.cpp file. If i hold Ctrl+click mouse on `#include <diagcom.hpp>` , the diagcom.hpp file will be opened on eclipse??

Comment: Is that a typo? `diagcom.hpp` vs `diacom.hpp`

Comment: @R Sahu. sorry i type wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#include "diacom.hpp"
```

instead of

```
#include <diacom.hpp>
```

The version with quotes is for project include files, and these files will be searched for in the specified include paths, as well as the directory of the source file itself.

The version with angle brackets is for system header files. These files will be searched for in the appropriate system header directories. Which directories are "appropriate" is system-dependent; the answer may depend on other compiler options, particularly the standard version, but you shouldn't have to worry about that.

The use of two different syntaxes is actually helpful to human readers as well, since you can tell at a glance whether an include is a standard library include or not.

Comment: I had trying to using #include "diagcom.hpp" but i still get the same error. If i using #include "sources/diagcom/diagcom.hpp", building succesfully

Comment: Is sources/diagcom in your list of include directories?